# Using ZedGraph as plotter(real time), force labels

Tags: c#, .net, graph, zedgraph

I'm stuck on two problems involving a Zedgraph.

I need to make it behave like a plotter. I have achieved this by setting the min and max value on the X scale when I need to update (the values are already in the graph, its a simulation).

Now the problem is when I activate the real time functionality sometimes(most of the time actually) the last label isn't drawn, I suspect because it doesn't fit in the pane. Is there any way to force the last label to draw (at the red circle, see image)?

[image: Missing label]

On to my second problem; Sometimes when the min and max scale are updated, the label lines(the lines in the yellow box, see image) shift a little to the right or left, same thing happens when I pan through the graph. This also causes the gridlines (dotted lines in the graph) to move, I would like to have those lines fixed on the same position.

Hope to find an answer, else I think I'll just use another graph library. Maybe any of you could point me to a good alternative with support for this kind of functionality. Though I absolutely love the zoom/pan features of zedGraph, not to mention the usefull functions in the context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, the problems were caused by the same issue. The date values I was using to set the scale contained miliseconds, this caused the scale to move just a little causing the label to disappear of the pane. I removed the miliseconds from the timestamp and now the graph is 'stable', meaning the scales don't move. And the last label is always drawn.